# My .gif animation doesnt show in google chrome? Any ideas why?

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, animated-gif

```
var loadUrl = "winners.php";
var ajax_load = '<div class="preloaders"><img src="img/preloader.gif" alt="Loadig..."></div>';

$(".page").click(function(){
    $(".main").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
});
```

I want to display my .gif animation in a web page, but it doesn't work in Google Chrome. With Firefox there is no problem. 
The idea is on a click to load the content and if it takes time to show the preloader.

Comment: Please add JSFiddle if possible.

Comment: I've removed `php` and `database` from the tags, since the question didn't appear to be related to either in any way, and I've added `animated-gif` and `google-chrome` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you output the preloading image with javascript. Then you see the image first when the site is loaded.

A better way is to output the image direktly on your site over HTML without javascript.

```
<div id="preloaders" style="display: block;"><img src="img/preloader.gif" alt="Loadig..."></div>
```

If javascript is loaded and all your content is ready hide the div.

```
$('#preloaders').hide();
```

Comment: This is what i see http://jsfiddle.net/8f64X/ it doesnt show the gif animation.. the route is correct.. and idf it not it would show "loading".

Comment: The image is not available. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) its possible that jsfiddle don't show it correct. Have you made the preloading image?